# Latest activity on a question.

Tags: support

I am unable to understand what is the activity on a question, as it shows the latest activity is 'today'. When i click on 'today' it shows the same page and same view and nothing there (interms of asnwers,votes,comments,comment votes, edits or anything new) that suggests of any activity. When I sort my questions it appears on top in order of 'recent'.The question i am referring to is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18554/is-this-class-of-functions-nonempty-nontrivial).
The only thing i notice is there was some increase in number of views. Please let me know if i am missing something.

Comment: See also http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/why-some-questions-are-marked-as-community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your profile page you can see that that question was bumped by [Community](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) 12 hours ago.   Even though there is no apparent lasting evidence of Community bumpings, I guess they count as "activity".